# Wicket validation message use label

Tags: forms, validation, label, wicket

I have some trouble showing the proper validation errors in my wicket form.
The labels are coupled to the input textfields with the 'wicket:for' attribute.

Example in the html file:

```
<label wicket:for="volumeField">Volume</label> <select wicket:id="volumeField"/>
```

In the properties file:

```
volumeField.Required=The field '${label}' is required
```

The replacement of `${label}` is not the value of the label, instead it is the key `volumeField`. Can I change it to the label value `Volume` in this case, without hardcoding it?

*The css classes `required` and `error` were only applied to the label. I found out that this had to do with the class `TextField` not properly applying the `required` tag, which was solved by overriding the `onComponentTag` method. (so this problem is solved)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use a `wicket:label` component inside the label for wicket to recognize the value of the label:

```
<label wicket:for="volumeField"><wicket:label>Volume</wicket:label></label>
```

After adding this, I can now use the `${label}` tag in my properties file to get 'Volume'